# Circumstantial: Can anything be 'circumstantial' but evidence?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I have come across the word circumstantial but I have only ever seen it used in the phrase 'circumstantial evidence'. I would like to ask if anything can be 'circumstantial' apart from evidence. When I say 'circumstantial' I mean it with the definition:

(adj) fully detailed and specific about particulars

not the legal definition as:

(adj) pointing indirectly towards someone's guilt but not conclusively proving it

If so, how is the word used? Thank you.

Comment: I see nothing at all unusual about a [*circumstantial **argument***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22circumstantial+argument%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (or [***topic***,](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22circumstantial+topic%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) [***details***,](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22circumstantial+details%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Many things [other than evidence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) can be *circumstantial* in the sense of a detailed account, for example:

- *[circumstantial narrative](https://books.google.com/books?id=FGJBAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GGuYVP6NFtPpaLb-gbAL&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ)*
- *[circumstantial journal](https://books.google.com/books?id=75ABAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GGuYVP6NFtPpaLb-gbAL&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg)*
- *[circumstantial account](https://books.google.com/books?id=9ToPAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GGuYVP6NFtPpaLb-gbAL&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBQ)*
- *[circumstantial memories](https://books.google.com/books?id=Hmzk0UJQlRIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mWuYVJ7RBpThat2BgeAL&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgK)*
- *[circumstantial deliveries](https://books.google.com/books?id=nRPjH-485vAC&pg=PP2&dq=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GGuYVP6NFtPpaLb-gbAL&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBA)*

However this meaning does seem to be mostly seen in older texts. Looking at [recent documents](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks&gws_rd=cr&ei=UWyYVPyTJdexabCmgtgE) shows a predominance of the meaning “incidental, dependent on circumstances”. (Source: visual comparison of the first few search hits.) For example:

- *[circumstantial bilinguals](https://books.google.com/books?id=btJhAAAAMAAJ&q=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&dq=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V2yYVPSfN43WauSagoAH&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBg)*
- *[circumstantial predictors](https://books.google.com/books?id=iyVYAAAAYAAJ&q=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&dq=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V2yYVPSfN43WauSagoAH&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA)*
- *[circumstantial causes and effects](https://books.google.com/books?id=EfRYAAAAMAAJ&q=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&dq=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SG2YVJjYMparae-kgugG&ved=0CCAQ6AEwATgK)*
- *[circumstantial authority](https://books.google.com/books?id=oeRAAQAAIAAJ&q=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&dq=%22circumstantial%22+-evidence&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V2yYVPSfN43WauSagoAH&ved=0CEUQ6AEwCA)*

The usage of the word [*circumstantial* seems to be declining](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=circumstantial%2Ccircumstantial+evidence%2Cevidence+is+circumstantial&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccircumstantial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccircumstantial%20evidence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevidence%20is%20circumstantial%3B%2Cc0). whereas the phrase “*circumstantial evidence*” remains as strong, making up about half the uses of the adjective (within the considerable margin of error of Google Books's statistics).

[image: circumstantial,circumstantial evidence,evidence is circumstantial]

Answer (score 0):

Per [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/circumstantial):

> (Of a description) containing full details:
>
> The picture was circumstantial and therefore convincing.

I can't say I hear/read it used much outside of a legal context, but that doesn't mean it's not acceptable; you may run the risk of misinterpretation by the audience if that is a concern.